# PHP cURL Post API

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to use BlockCypher API for accepting Ethereum. From their documentation (https://dev.blockcypher.com/eth/#address-endpoint), they ask to send a cURL request to get an address back.

I've tried this :-

```
  <?php
$a = "https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/eth/main/addrs?token=my_token";
$b = file_get_contents($a);
var_dump($b);
?>
```

Which gives me this error :-

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/eth/main/addrs?token=my_token): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in C:\wamp\www\x\backend\dev\t.php on line 3
```

If I try to run the URL directly on web, I get this error :-

```
Endpoint not found. Please check your URL for typos and make sure you're using the correct  HTTP method (GET, POST, etc).
```

What wrong am I doing?

Comment: using the wrong url? I'm assuming you've censored your actual token, and didn't literally send `my_token` to the service?

Comment: @MarcB
Correct, I've just censored it. In actual, I've used my original token there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cURL request is done via the [cURL library](http://php.net/curl). They are quite probably blocking requests from other clients that do not identify (via User-Agent string) as cURL. You are using file_get_contents, which is easier but carries a "PHP" User-Agent string.

See [cURL examples from the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php) for further information.

**EDIT:** Now it seems to me you read the API documentation wrong. There is no endpoint `/addrs` for the GET method, the documentation you linked to "returns more information about an address’ transactions than the Address Balance Endpoint, but sacrifices some response speed in the process." To generate an adress you must POST to the [generate-adress endpoint](https://dev.blockcypher.com/eth/#generate-address-endpoint) of that API.

Comment: Did not work for me. Getting the same error as running the URL in browser.

Comment: Then it's most likely a security issue with your API key, IP address range or something else. Did you try the curl command line tool as per their example?

Comment: did some more further testing and it worked.  Thanks :)

Comment: Lemme guess, you used POST now instead of GET? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try This code it will work:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();


curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/eth/main/addrs/738d145faabb1e00cf5a017588a9c0f998318012",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST =>0,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER =>0,
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```